# Problem about Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Could someone help me with the following problem?

Let be $X$ a real normed space , $f,g\in{X^*}$ ($\|f\|=\|g\|=1$) and  $0<r\leq1$  such that $|f(x)|\leq{r}$ $\forall{x\in{\ker(g)}},\|x\|\leq{1}$.
Prove that either $\|f-g\|\leq{2r}$ or $\|f+g\|\leq{2r}$.

I am trying to use Hahn-Banach Theorem to $f_{\ker(g)}$, but I don't get nothing .

Thanks.

Comment: How can $f$ be bounded when it's linear unless $f \equiv 0$?

Comment: @md2perpe I take it that when you say "$f$ bounded" you mean $|f(x)|\le c$ for all $x$. Why do you think that's so?

Comment: I saw $|f(x)|\leq{r}$ in a subspace, but I missed the restriction to $\|x\| \leq 1.$ Sorry for that.

Comment: do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? Check $X=\mathbb R^2$, $g(x,y)=y$ and $f(x,y)=(x+y)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, @Jochen you're right, so what can we say if we change $r$ for $2r$?.(I've just edited again the question)

Comment: Did you try $X=\mathbb R^2$? Perhaps with different norms $\|(x,y)\|_t^2=x^2+ty^2$ for a parameter $t>0$.

Comment: Yes, @Jochen I have been looking for a counterexample but  it sems to me that this is true

Answer (score 2):

Well, as long as we're willing to change the question, it's not hard to show that $\|f+g\|\le 1+r$ or $\|f-g\|\le 1+r$.

Let $Z$ be the kernel of $g$. We have $\|f|_Z\|\le r$,  so Hahn-Banach shows that there exists $F$ with $F|_Z=f|_Z$ and $\|F\|\le r$.

Now $F-f$ vanishes on the kernel of $g$, so  there exists $c$ with $$F-f=cg.$$Note that $|c|=\|F-f\|\le 1+r$.

If $0\le c\le 1+r$ then $$\|f+g\|\le\|f+cg\|+|c-1|\le r+1.$$
Similarly if $-1-r\le c\le 0$ then $\|f-g\|\le 1+r$.

Comment: Why does $\operatorname{Ker} g \subseteq \operatorname{Ker} (F - f)$ imply that $F - f = cg$, for some scalar $c$?

Comment: @mechanodroid If $g=0$ then $F-f=0$. If $g\ne0$ choose $x_0$ with $g(x_0)=1$ and let $c=(F-f)(x_0)$. (Note that $X$ is spanned by $Z,x_0$...)